# Installing ubuntu 14.04 alongside windows 8.1 UEFI

Tags: windows, gparted

I'm on an ASUS F550L with Windows 8.1

I can see from windows : partition   C: and D:  of about similar size

But from gparted Ubuntu 14:04 LTS I can see:

```
/dev/sda  unknown 
/dev/sda1 efi        
/dev/sda2 ntfs
/dev/sda3 unknown
/dev/sda4 ntfs
/dev/sda5 ntfs
/dev/sda6 ntfs
empty spce
```

How can I find where to locate my `/`, `home` and `swap`?

Comment: You use Windows to shrink the main Windows NTFS partition and reboot so it can run chkdsk and fix itself to new size. Make sure fast boot or always on hibernation is off and usually better to have secure boot off. Be sure to boot installer flash drive in UEFI mode. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI AND: http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-uefi-supported-windows-8-system And: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, you could use the following command in your terminal(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>) to locate these.

`df -h` for file system mount points:

```
phlin@ubuntu:~$ df -h<br>
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on<br>
/dev/sda1       451G  270G  159G   63% /
udev            3.9G  4.0K  3.9G    1% /dev
tmpfs           786M  948K  785M    1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M    0% /run/lock
none            3.9G   18M  3.9G    1% /run/shm
```

`swapon -s` for swap:

```
phlin@ubuntu:~$ swapon -s
Filename                Type        Size    Used    Priority
/dev/sda5                               partition   8257532 0   -1
```